# Cut image C# without losing quality of the original image

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, rectangles

Hi I'm trying of cut/obtain a part of an image with this method:

```
private Image RecortarImagen(Image img, NLAttributes attr)
    {
        try
        {
            Rectangle cropArea = new Rectangle(attr.BoundingRect.X, attr.BoundingRect.Y, attr.BoundingRect.Width, attr.BoundingRect.Height);
            Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
            Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea,
            bmpImage.PixelFormat);
            return (Image)(bmpCrop);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

NLAtrributes contain 4 int for define (x, y, width, height)

The problem that I present is when I show the image in a PictureBox this appear rotated, not maintain the original position[image: Image error]

**This not occur in all cases, it's the strangest thing**

What method can be use for do this cut and maintain the quality of the original images?

Comment: Dont use `RotateFlip` if dont want to rotate or flip the image.  Not really a "quality" thing

Comment: What is NLAttributes? have you tried just putting in normal integer values for creating the rectangle?  Maybe the way you're pulling the integer values from the attr object is causing an error, such as a method call is missing `()` or is improperly constructed.

Comment: NLAttributes contain the 4 integers for use for create the rectangle

Comment: Is that original image viewed in the program, though? Because images nowadays can contain extra information on camera orientation. This extra information are merely "viewing instructions" for photo display programs though, and they will be ignored when loading the image in .Net.

Comment: With respect to this, i can observe this interpretation when load the image using openFileDialog example: The image is vertical 1600 (Height) x 1200 (Width). but with this line: **Bitmap source = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName);** when i see the properties of source appear inverted Width 1600 and Height 1200. What can I do? Need can cut the image